# How to use remove0() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, series

I am a beginner in Python and am trying to remove the order object in a series expansion.

f.series(x, x0, 2).remove0()

AttributeError:'Add' object has no attribute 'remove0'

Please help!!!

My code:

```
x =sympy.symbols("x")
f = sympy.Function("f")(x)
sympy.series(f,x).remove0()
```

Comment: What module are you using?

Comment: I am using sympy

Comment: please include minimum reproducable example

Comment: From [this page](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html), the method is called `removeO` (with a capital letter oh), *not* `remove0` (with the digit zero), which is what you used. It's named this way because the method `remove`s the `O`rder term. This is just a simple typo.

Comment: Solved. Thank you for helping!!!

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html), the method is called `removeO` (with a capital letter oh), *not* `remove0` (with the digit zero), which is what you used. It's named this way because the method `remove`s the `O`rder term. If you run

```
import sympy

x =sympy.symbols("x")
f = sympy.Function("f")(x)
sympy.series(f,x).removeO()
```

the result is now

```
x**5*Subs(Derivative(f(_x), (_x, 5)), _x, 0)/120 + x**4*Subs(Derivative(f(_x), (_x, 4)), _x, 0)/24 + x**3*Subs(Derivative(f(_x), (_x, 3)), _x, 0)/6 + x**2*Subs(Derivative(f(_x), (_x, 2)), _x, 0)/2 + x*Subs(Derivative(f(_x), _x), _x, 0) + f(0)
```